# Type mismatch error when iterating over cells in a range

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to run the following vb code on my spreadsheet but I am getting an error during the Randge that there is a data type mismatch. I am just trying to lock the cells where the value is 0. There are some cells with #NA values Any ideas?

```
Sub Test()
Dim Cell As Range
Set MyPlage = Range("J6:J1074")
For Each Cell In MyPlage.Cells
    If Not IsError(Cell) Then
        If Range("J6:J1074").Value = "0" Then
       Range("J6:J1074").Locked = True
        End If


    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Tip: When you iterate over the cells in range, you should be checking the current target you're iterating on, not the whole range. See @simoco's answer. Notice how he uses `Cell.Value` rather than the whole range. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim MyPlage As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        Set MyPlage = .Range("J6:J1074")
        For Each Cell In MyPlage
            If Not IsError(Cell) Then
                If Cell.Value = "0" Then
                    Cell.Locked = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .Protect
    End With

End Sub
```

BTW, it's better to change `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets("SheetName")`

Comment: +1: This will work, but it's good to point out that locking a cell will not work unless the sheet is protected. Let's hope OP knows this, though.

Comment: Thanks, when I run the macro nothing happens and the cells arent locked?

Comment: @user1342164: As I pointed out, check my comment. You have to protect the sheet for it to be locked. Highlight any `0`-valued cell in your range and press `Ctrl-1`. Go to the `Protection` tab. You'll see `Locked` is checked, but there's a warning there.

Comment: @user1342164, see please comment above. BK201 right. You need to protect sheet. And I've updated answer

Comment: Thanks, problem is I want them to be able to modify the other cells. If my cell contains the value "$100" it cant be modified now?

Comment: Updated answer again..see it please, and yes, it's possible with new code