# Error Mismatch 13 on Case & Range

Tags: vba, excel

I basically want to do some formatting via VBA based on certain criteria. For reasons, I need to avoid conditional formatting.

I keep getting this error message and this row is highlighted...
"Case Is = "Same""

The code works for like half of two columns and gives this error. What can I do to apply this to my ranges?

```
Sub DifferenceReport()

        Dim c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, CellRange As Range
        Set c1 = Sheets("Difference").Range("G3:G200")
        Set c2 = Sheets("Difference").Range("H3:H200")
        Set c3 = Sheets("Difference").Range("K3:K200")
        Set c4 = Sheets("Difference").Range("N3:N200")
        Set c5 = Sheets("Difference").Range("Q3:Q200")
        Set c6 = Sheets("Difference").Range("T3:T200")
        Set c7 = Sheets("Difference").Range("Z3:Z200")
        Set c8 = Sheets("Difference").Range("AC3:AC200")
        Set c9 = Sheets("Difference").Range("AF3:AF200")
        Set c10 = Sheets("Difference").Range("AI3:AI200")
        Set CellRange = Union(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10)

        For Each cell In CellRange
            Select Case cell.Value
                Case Is = "Same"
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                Case Is = ""
                Case Else
            End Select
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It's just - `Case "Same"`

Comment: I still get the same error with Case "Same"

Comment: you need to remove the Case Is = "" to Case ""

Comment: Any error values in those cells?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type mismatch error when iterating over cells in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409396/type-mismatch-error-when-iterating-over-cells-in-a-range)

Comment: @TimWilliams - `Case "xyz"` is just shorthand for the fully expanded `Case Is = "xyz"` - both are legal.  AFAIK "Is =" is just the default operation.

Comment: @YowE3K agreed. It's overly verbose and awkward though. Anyway, this question is a dupe, OP needs to wrap their `Select Case` block with an `If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then`  check.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - or include a `Case CVErr(xlErrNA)` (etc) condition prior to getting to a condition where it needs to cast the `Variant/Error` to a `String`

Comment: Turns out there was an error in my ranges. I no longer get the Error Mismatch, but now it wont' color any of the cells "Same" to what I have. The macro kinda just runs flat.

Answer (score 0):

you may be experiencing some "case" issue

in that case you could use:

```
    Select Case UCase(cell.Value) '<--| consider the UPPERCASE string of your current cell value
        Case "SAME" '<---| and compare it against "SAME"
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
        Case ""
        Case Else
    End Select
```

furthermore you may want to use a more concise `CellRange` setting and a more efficient way of looping through cells with "text" values only

```
Sub DifferenceReport()
    Dim CellRange As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("Difference")
        Set CellRange = Intersect(.Range("G3:AI200"), .Range("G:G, H:H, K:K, N:N, Q:Q, T:T, Z:Z, AC:AC, AF:AF, AI:AI"))
    End With

    For Each cell In CellRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        Select Case UCase(cell.Value)
            Case "SAME"
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
            Case ""
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```